# What is the difference between "dichotomous", "binary", "boolean", etc.?

Tags: differences, adjectives

To classify species we use a method called: dichotomous biological key. It works base on true and false cycles. In computer sciences true and fulse working is called boolean and binary is a 0 and 1 system (which is like true and false).

What is the difference between them? Can I use term "Binary biological key"? Are these really different?

(I have edited this question following Daniel's and MT-Head's comments.)

Comment: I'm no programmer, but I thought what you are referring to was a *boolean*, not *binary*.  Binary's a number system, boolean's true/false.

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: It's not quite correct that "true and false working is called Binary".  The **number system** is called *binary* (meaning base-2, as opposed to *decimal*, or base-10).  However, *binary* as an adjective just means "appearing in pairs" - e.g. ["binary star"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_star) or ["binary explosive"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_explosive).  If you want to specify that something can have one of two states - not more, not less - then "dichotomous" is an excellent word.  If you're talking about philosophy, try [*Manichaean*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manichaean).

Comment: The number system, the logical system, the mathematics, and the cladistic system are all mixed up here. Not to mention their terminology, which is all over the map. Anyone who's unclear on the concepts and their distinctions and limitations shouldn't be writing about them, or attempting to refer to them terminologically.

Comment: I am not native. I supposed maybe "Binary biological key" is Correct just like "dichotomous biological key"

Comment: (*Sigh*) What is it that you want to say, and who do you want to say it to, and what do you want them to understand from your saying? By the way, "binary biological key" doesn't mean the same thing as "dichotomous biological key", though they're equally correct.

Comment: @JohnLawler I wouldn't say equally. Anything that is dichotomous is binary - since it's split into two parts, but not everything that's binary is dichotomous - since the two parts may not be due to a split. As such *dichotomous* is more precise than *binary*.

Comment: Now I know that "boolean biological key" is incorrect. but I am still confused on others.

Comment: The point is not the dictionary definitions of the terms, but their usage in particular technical contexts, where generalized dictionary meaning is trumped, as usual, by local conventions and idioms. "Official" meanings are, alas, not always official.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Boolean* refers to Boolean algebra, named after George Boole.

While Boolean true/false values have other uses in computer science - a heavy use of it today - the thing that makes it Boolean isn't just that it can such values can only be *true* or *false*, but that one can also do Boolean algebra on it (e.g. in the expression `x ∧ (y ∨ ¬z)` expressed in computer code as e.g. `x && (y || !z)` (C-style), `x AND (y OR NOT z)` (Basic-style) and others). If we had a programming language that allowed of branching on a two-way value, but didn't allow for such Boolean algebra, then such values wouldn't truly be Boolean.

You don't do Boolean algebra with a dichotomous key, so it would would be incorrect to call it *Boolean*.

*Binary* means anything involving two things. A dichotomous key is hence a binary approach, but this meaning is different to some more specific meanings of *binary* (it has nothing to do with the binary number system, for example).

A *dichotomy* refers to splitting something into two parts. Hence everything that is dichotomous is binary, but not everything that is binary is dichotomous.

So, *Boolean* is wrong, *binary* is valid, but not as precise as *dichotomous* which is completely correct.

Answer (score 3):

In most programming languages, boolean *variables* are either `true` or `false`; in Ruby, however, a boolean variable is `true` only if it is neither `false` nor `nil`. Moreover, [Boolean operations](http://www.wolfram.com/products/mathematica/newin7/content/IndustrialStrengthBooleanComputation/) can operate on objects other than boolean variables, and allow *don't-care* values as valid inputs.

A binary operation involves a choice between two, and only two, mutually exclusive alternatives, and thus does accomplish a *dichotomy*. However, *binary* as an adjective simply describes something that consists of two parts.

In biology, *dichotomous key* is a standard term to the extent that you will find it in most dictionaries:

> **dichotomous key**, *n.* : *biology* : a key to classification based on a choice between two alternative characters [MW Unabridged]

There isn't a compelling reason to call it anything else.

Comment: +1 for using the standard term for the domain.  Using 'boolean' in a biology paper would probably be as jarring as using 'dichotomous key' in a Ruby program, even though English-wise they mean almost the same thing.

Comment: @Lynn it wouldn't just be jarring, it would be wrong. If you can't do Boolean algebra with it, it isn't Boolean.

Answer (score 2):

The words mean somewhat similar things in this context (a boolean value is either true or false and never both, so it could be considered a common example of a dichotomy). Boolean, however, contains a concept of "right", where dichotomous only contains the concept of being different.

Very often in biology there isn't a clear mapping to "true" and "false", so calling it boolean could misleadingly imply that there is. Indeed, from a brief googling of this method, it seems to not include the concept that one member of these "couplets" is right and the other is wrong, merely that they're distinct, so dichotomous is more right than boolean.

In some other case, where all else were equal, the convention would win out, so I'd (for example) still recommend to call it a dichotomous biological key and not a boolean biological key.

Comment: A biological example: 1.If it have 8 legs, go to 2, else go to 3.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dichotomous key represented as a branching diagram in a text book that you wanted to automate into a piece of software, then you would almost certainly use boolean variables to track each decision point.

So the logic is the same in each case, but the language conventions adopted by each discipline  involve different labels.

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the documented definition of the term ***Dichotomous key*** (a key for the identification of organisms based on a series of choices between alternative characters [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dichotomous%20key)); A written tool for identification of plants and animals. It is written as a sequence of paired questions, the choice of which determines the next pair of questions until a name or identification is reached. [Wikipedia](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dichotomous_key))?

If not, you would probably better chose another term instead.

The different meanings of *[dichotomous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dichotomous)*, *[binary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/binary)* and *[boolean](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/boolean)* are already explained well.