# What is the word for deciding between two equally pleasant alternatives?

Tags: single-word-requests

A word like Dilemma.I know of deciding between two unpleasant alternatives.

Comment: A ***dilemma*** is a "difficult choice" - usually (but not *always*) between "undesirable" alternatives.

Comment: Thank You @fumbleFingers. I did not know this.

I know the expression "Between a rock and a hard place."

Comment: An abundance of riches.

Comment: About 144 writers in Google Books have faced [*an **enviable** dilemma*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22an+enviable+dilemma%22) Presumably in most/all cases because all available options are desirable.

Comment: Similar: [Word that means having a choice between two options](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/419481)

Answer (score 1):

There is not one word other than "dilemma" that fits into the paradigm of the picture you are trying to paint with your words.

The word dilemma is actually from the root words di- usually indicating two but could mean many and, lemma- which (ironically in your case) refers to the many ways of saying the same word within the context of a sentence or paragraph.. the example used from Wiki was:  "go", "goes", "going", "went", and "gone".

In other words the word dilemma is meant to describe a literary dilemma between having to choose from two or more ways of saying the same thing.  In our society the word has come to have a connotation towards a negative comparison unless qualified by an adjective or some other mechanism to denote it's positive characters.  One has to simply describe the dilemma to the reader:

"I was faced with an amazingly beautiful dilemma between...."... or you could simply refer to the choices already stated or stated to come as being a dilemma and let the reader put the "feeling" or emotive quality to the dilemma based on the details of the scene you are painting.  As rich as the English language is there are not enough words yet developed for everything that the mind can wish to express.  Thus one is faced with many dilemma's when trying to pick the best ways to describe ones thoughts and ideas into the spoken word.