# What's the word for sentences like - "There are two kind of people in this world - those who like ice-cream and those who don't"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I know there's a word for it and it probably is similar to oxymoron, but I can't put my finger on it.

Edit - The sentences is generally characterised by having binary choices with no added information. i.e Things are either "A" or "not A"

Comment: aphorism, maxim, adage are a few that come to mind.

Comment: @lambie There is a word specifically for this kind of sentence. Although aphorism fits the criteria, its applicable to lot of other things too.

Comment: @Cascabel Its a special case. It's not just binary choices, plus there is no added information i.e everything can be classified into "A" and "Not A".

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at but you could read this: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThereAreTwoKindsOfPeopleInTheWorld

Comment: [What is the word for always yes ... or always no ... never in-between](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/316344/what-is-the-word-for-always-yes-100-or-always-no-0-never-in-between) gives answers like 'dichotomous', 'binary', 'either-or', 'yes-no, 'disjunctive' (and 'disjoint' is mentioned), 'exclusive disjuntion'. These describe situations, not sentences in the first instance, but acceptance of any of these answers makes the question a duplicate. You need to provide an example sentence to show that your question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I think the term tautology (specifically a logical tautology) could apply here.

Comment: Yes. This is it.

Comment: Tautology is a much wider concept than what the question is about.